# Node js cannot post /myaction

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I made up a form service.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/myaction" method="post">
    <select>
          <option value="get">GET</option>
          <option value="post">POST</option>
          <option value="del">DELETE</option>
          <option value="put">PUT</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="URL"></input>
    <input type="text" placeholder="STATUS"></input>
    <input type="text" placeholder="TYPE"></input>
    <textarea id="something" name="something" rows="14" cols="100" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
    <div><input class="cbutton" type="submit" value="create"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the server.js file is

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server running on 8080...');
});
```

app.js file is

```
const port = 8080;

var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: false;
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('form');
 res.sendFile("service.html"); //if html file is within public directory
});

app.post('/myaction', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
   response = {
      body:req.body.something
   };
   console.log(response);
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})

app.listen(port);
```

I have an entire bootstrap & want the same to run everything using node.js server
When from the cmd line I open turn on the server.js file & run localhost:8080/service.html I want the part in the body to be printed the json form as a response 
But when i submit it says cannot post /myaction

Help appreciated thanks. New to nodejs

Answer (score 0):

html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <form action="/myaction" method="post">
    <select>
      <option value="get">GET</option>
      <option value="post">POST</option>
      <option value="del">DELETE</option>
      <option value="put">PUT</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="URL"></input>
    <input type="text" placeholder="STATUS"></input>
    <input type="text" placeholder="TYPE"></input>
    <textarea id="something" name="something" rows="14" cols="100" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
    <div>
      <input class="cbutton" type="submit" value="create"/>       </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const port = 8080;

var express = require('express'),
app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/service.html");
});

app.post('/myaction', function (req, res) {
  response = {
    body:req.body.something
  };
  console.log(response);
  res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})

app.listen(port);
```

run this app.js file as node application and you don't need server.js file that you have mentioned above and it works fine.

Comment: Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

Comment: remove res.render('form')  in app.get('/')

Comment: I removed now it says.. Cannot GET /service.html

Comment: cannot get indicates that it is not a defined route and moreover http://localhost:8080/ loads the service.html file not http://localhost:8080/service.html

Comment: Thanks I got it done. One more thing is that I am working on the bootstrap & when I am trying to load through node.js it doesnt load the css files. Can you help about that pls?

Comment: can you post the href attribute value of bootstrap css file

Comment: <link href=“/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css” type=“stylesheet”>

Comment: rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css”

Comment: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) defines location for the the static files like html, css and js files. So keep the static files in public folder or changes '/public' in app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) to folder where you are keeping the static files. If bootstrap.min.css file is in public/css foler then href=“/public/css/bootstrap.min.css”

Comment: I dont have a public folder instead i have a folder named on the proj. Suppose the name of the directory is wire.. so am i supposed to keep the name as /wire?